# Mach-O-Link error

Tags: ios, objective-c, static-libraries, mach

I'm currently working on an app that includes in app purchases.
Being tired of having to copy paste the same class files in all projects i decided to create a static library.

I followed several of the available guides on the web on how to create a static library for IOS but i always seem to be running into problems.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NWStorePackage", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in StoreTableViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

The same error is displayed for the arm64 architecture

i linked the library, added the header files. updated the header search paths, updated the framework paths. don't know what more i can do...
I used the following script.

```
# define output folder environment variable  
UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER=${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-universal

# Step 1. Build Device and Simulator versions
xcodebuild -target ${PROJECT_NAME} ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO -configuration ${CONFIGURATION} -sdk iphoneos  BUILD_DIR="${BUILD_DIR}" BUILD_ROOT="${BUILD_ROOT}"
xcodebuild -target ${PROJECT_NAME} -configuration ${CONFIGURATION} -sdk iphonesimulator -arch i386 BUILD_DIR="${BUILD_DIR}" BUILD_ROOT="${BUILD_ROOT}"

# make sure the output directory exists 
mkdir -p "${UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER}"

# Step 2. Create universal binary file using lipo
lipo -create -output "${UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER}/lib${PROJECT_NAME}.a" "${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphoneos/lib${PROJECT_NAME}.a" "${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphonesimulator/lib${PROJECT_NAME}.a"

# Last touch. copy the header files. Just for convenience
cp -R "${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphoneos/include" "${UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER}/"
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you checked that all the headers are copied in the right directory (in the one that you specified in header path of your application setting?).

If the header is not generated, maybe you have missed to add header to copy file step. Or you do not have Copy Header Build Phase:

[image]

Comment: These are my settings.
[Image 1](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2189372/fora/stackexchange/1.png)
[Image 2](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2189372/fora/stackexchange/2.png)
[Image 3](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2189372/fora/stackexchange/3.png)

Comment: I suppose that your headers are in another directories that your SOURCE? In that case, you have to specify these paths in "Header Search Path" (image 3).